# Using CGI page as directory index in Boa web server

Tags: indexing, cgi, directoryindex, boa

I am using Boa web server on an ARM based board.
I wish to use a cgi script as the home page.

In boa.conf, I used the option

```
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
```

However, when entering the IP of the host board in my browser, all I get is error 403, and the page is only accessible if I manually add /index.cgi to the address bar.

When changing back to

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

everything works fine.

I've tried playing around with Alias and ScriptAlias but those didn't help.
I realize I can use an html redirect from index.html as a last resort, but I feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found [this patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/boa/patches/23/)

It is written around boa-0.94.14rc20 while I'm using boa-0.94.13

I've managed to get it to compile and work by changing the following line:

```
req->cgi_type = CGI;
```

to

```
reg->is_cgi = CGI;
```

This still isn't perfect though since passing parameters to the cgi page in boa.conf still results in error 403.